# OSX 10.9 - Two finger click for middle click?

Tags: macos, trackpad

I just got a new macbook (OSX 10.9), I used one previously (also recent OSX version) where I had 2-finger click to act as a middle click in firefox (open new tab, close tab, etc). I also had right click turned on (clicking on bottom right of the trackpad).

I downloaded BetterTouchTool, but the option for "Two Finger Click" is not there. I tried disabling Mac built-in two finger commands to get it to appear but no luck - three/four/five finger click is there, but not 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BetterTouchTool does not support two finger tap/click actions. There was an [experimental version](http://blog.boastr.net/experimental-2-finger-click/) a long time ago but it was implemented in a 'hacky' way and never really worked right.

BetterTouchTool does let you set up a **TipTap to middle click**, so that you can press with a second finger whilst your first is down (sort of like a two finger click but with a delay) to activate a middle click:

## [image] → [image]

Alternatively, you can set up a tap/press with three fingers to middle click in BetterTouchTool. This is supported fine:

[image]

If you're really looking for a two-finger click, [**KeyRemap4MacBook**](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) lets you remap right click to middle click using a private.xml such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Right Click to Middle Click</name>
    <identifier>remapRightClickToMiddleClick</identifier>
    <autogen>
      —PointingButtonToPointingButton—
      PointingButton::RIGHT, PointingButton::MIDDLE
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See [private.xml documentation](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) for more information and to limit to certain apps.

Comment: Weird, I remember doing the two finger tap on links in firefox (I never used any other tool besides BTT). I also had right click enabled.

Comment: @Madd0g Maybe you were doing a TipTap (see edit)?

Comment: Do you use Macs tools to make the animated gif :)

Comment: @Buscar [Sure do](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/)

Comment: I'm giving up, I'll try the TipTap method as an alternative. I don't want to give up the right click feature. Thanks for the hard work @grgarside. EDIT: ouch, the fingers have to be side by side for TipTap, I thought the second finger could be anywhere.

Comment: @Madd0g Yes, the two fingers for a TipTap have to be next to each other like a normal secondary click on the trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it was added, but BetterTouchTool does support two finger click and tap gestures now: [image: BetterTouchTool two finger gestures]