# Middle click and right click on trackpad

Tags: macos, trackpad

How can I set up middle click and right click on a trackpad? I would prefer something like:

- middle click = click with two fingers,
- right click = click with 3 fingers.

Currently, only the right click is enabled, using: System Preferences | Trackpad | Point & Click | Secondary Click = click with two fingers.

I am using MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021), macOS Monterey Version 12.6.1.

**RELATED:**

- [Triple finger tap for middle click?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7110/329079)
- [OSX 10.9 - Two finger click for middle click?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126632/329079)

Comment: [I can't add this really as an answer, because I've no direct experience with it.] Mac has never natively supported middle-click, even on a three-button mouse. It has no native functionality supporting it either. You'll need a 3rd party utility - there are a few here - https://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/how-to-middle-click-on-macos-using-trackpad-or-magic-mouse/ & then some way of telling the Mac what you expect it to do in response.